# How can I resolve this problem with "while"

Tags: javascript

I want to make a timer using while, and when I lunch the code in Chrome, the Chrome don't load.

I am making this:

```
var time = 0;

        while (time < 5) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                tempo[0].innerHTML = time;
                time++;
            }, 1000);
        }
```

I expect when time it gets to 5, javascript will exit the loop and execute the next action

Comment: The `setTimeout()` out function schedules a function to be called at some time in the future, but it returns **immediately**.

Comment: The callback first passed to `setTimeout` will be called after the `while` loop will be finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `async` and `await`

```js
var time = 0;
var result = document.querySelector('#display')
async function start(){
  while (time < 5) {
   await new Promise(res => {
     setTimeout(function(){
      result.innerHTML = time;
      time++;
      res();
    }, 1000);
   }) 
  }
}
start()
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```